# Can't open/display my web application properly in IE 10

Tags: java, javascript, css, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

We have a huge HMI and SCADA web application which provides data collection facility from almost any plant floor and provides visualization and analysis facility over it.

The product is based on three technologies. Front end and server side is in JavaScript, Java, and database engines are in C++ connected via JNI.

In the front end, we have practically used HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to create our own windowing environment. Every window is an iFrame in which we dynamically load an applet. So the web application runs Java applet code in HTML iframes in a windowing environment with all the windowing environment features applied (like dragging, closing, opening multiple Windows etc.)

The product has been running absolutely perfect in IE9 and earlier version. However, as soon as we upgraded IE 10, we have been facing serious problems. Some are related to functions/properties in JavaScript that are not supported in IE10.

Majorly we digged and fixed these issues in IE10:

- Many methods are no more accessible without 'this' pointer in JavaScript: We added 'this' pointer to resolve it
- element.getAttribute ("style") is not supported in IE10. We used the alternative document.style to get it done

However, after these small fixations, we have ommitted all the JavaScript/HTML exceptions but the web page doesn't display itself properly. We consultant MSDN IE 10 compatibility cookbook and a lot of other forums to understand that if a webpage isn't following standards, then the possibility of the webpage not displaying itself correctly is high as IE10 imposes strict standards.

We added doctype and metainf tags in all HTMLs so that our browser mode in F12 developer tools is IE10 and document mode is IE9 standards but still no improvement.

Its been around a month we are searching on this issue. Reading documents, support, and problems with IE10 but couldn't really locate the real problem.

**Page should be displayed as follows:**

[image]

**Currently the page is displayed as follows:**

[image]

Comment: I guess there is a lot of things this could be and it's really hard to help without being able to access the site ourselves. What doctype are you using? Also maybe try running the site through this tool: http://validator.w3.org/ and this one: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Are there error messages in the console? Did you do basic debugging like stepping though?

Comment: @BillyMoat: Following is doctype and meta inf that I am using:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Comment: @RoToRa: There are no error messages at all. Not in JS and not in Java. The web application is deployed on a local server.

Comment: I did mean the JS console. Can't you step through the JS code and find the place where it fails?

Comment: umm...It doesn't fail anywhere. If I explain you technically, there are a lot of calls in setTimeout() function, to make them aSynch. It throws no exception on the way to its launch, but do you suggest me that I debug it line by line, despite the fact?

Comment: Yes, exactly. With "the place where it fails" I meant no where an exception happens, but where it no longer does what you expect.

Comment: wait, your x-ua-compatible meta element is above your doctype? switch that, then tell us what you see

Comment: No, meta element is inside <head> tag. and Doctype is written on the top of the document.

Comment: @RoToRa: I debugged the whole code, it didn't fail at any point, neither it gave me any anomalous behavior. It is executing just fine. The problem lies with rendering and display. :(

Comment: @ZakiImtiaz Sorry, I never had anything like that. I guess I can't help you then :-(

Comment: @RoToRa..thank you..help appreciated!

Comment: Guys. I have added an answer to this post. Please see and comment. A narrowed down problem!

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I have worked this example by breaking in it a very small part and found out the problem.

In IE10, if a `<iframe>` is present inside a `<td>`, the height width attributes of an Iframe given in percentage doesn't pay much heed to the height width of its parent.

Like in the following example, iFrame with the id 'test' takes height width = 100%. While its parent's height is 1px. *When you run this in IE10, the frame appears to be very large in height and shows anomalous behavior*

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>


</HEAD>
<BODY id="WESWinDesktop"  >
<table id=WESStructure width="100%" height="100%" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td id="WESMainWinTitleBarCont" height="1px">       this is 'td' for iframe
            <iframe  id="test" src="" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="WESMainWinMenuBar" height="20">     menu bar
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="100%" >content

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="WESMainWinStatus" height="20">  status bar
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have tried the same thing by putting a `<div>` instead of a `<td>` but the behavior is the same. So I guess there is something wrong with the way IE10 interprets width height attributes of an iframe.